# React Full Width Text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I found this web-component `https://github.com/pomber/full-width-text` but it relies on Polymer to function.

Does anyone know how I can extract the useful parts and use it as a React component?

I've also tried an alternative called React FitText but it wasn't a great solution as the text overflowed the container height etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - I found the perfect package for this...

npmjs.com/package/react-textfit

After looking at this for entirely too long, this is a great solution!